# Is it safe to get values from a java.util.HashMap from multiple threads (no modification)?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap

There is a case where a map will be constructed, and once it is initialized, it will never be modified again.  It will however, be accessed (via get(key) only) from multiple threads.  Is it safe to use a `java.util.HashMap` in this way?

(Currently, I'm happily using a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`, and have no measured need to improve performance, but am simply curious if a simple `HashMap` would suffice.  Hence, this question is *not* "Which one should I use?" nor is it a performance question.  Rather, the question is "Would it be safe?")

Comment: Many answers here are correct regarding mutual exclusion from running threads, but incorrect regarding memory updates.  I've voted up/down accordingly, but there are still many incorrect answers with positive votes.

Comment: @Heath Borders, if the instance a was statically initialized unmodifiable HashMap, it should be safe for concurrent read (as other threads couldn't have missed updates as there were no updates), right?

Comment: If it's statically initialized and never modified outside of the static block, then it might be ok because all static initialization is synchronized by the `ClassLoader`. That's worth a separate question on its own. I'd still explicitly synchronize it and profile to verify that it was causing real performance issues.

Comment: @HeathBorders - what do you mean by "memory updates"? The JVM is a formal model which defines things like visibility, atomicity, _happens-before_ relationships, but doesn't use terms like "memory updates". You should clarify, preferably using terminology from the JLS.

Comment: @Dave - I assume you aren't still looking for answer after 8 years, but for the record, the key confusion in nearly all the answers is that they focus on _the actions you take on the map object_. You've already explained that you never modify the object, so that is all irrelevant. The only potential "gotcha" then is **how you publish the reference** to the `Map`, which you didn't explain. If you don't do it safely, it is not safe. If you do it safely, _it is_. Details in my answer.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your idiom is safe **if and only if** the reference to the `HashMap` is *safely published*. Rather than anything relating the internals of `HashMap` itself, *safe publication* deals with how the constructing thread makes the reference to the map visible to other threads.

Basically, the only possible race here is between the construction of the `HashMap` and any reading threads that may access it before it is fully constructed. Most of the discussion is about what happens to the state of the map object, but this is irrelevant since you never modify it - so the only interesting part is how the `HashMap` reference is published.

For example, imagine you publish the map like this:

```
class SomeClass {
   public static HashMap<Object, Object> MAP;

   public synchronized static setMap(HashMap<Object, Object> m) {
     MAP = m;
   }
}
```

... and at some point `setMap()` is called with a map, and other threads are using `SomeClass.MAP` to access the map, and check for null like this:

```
HashMap<Object,Object> map = SomeClass.MAP;
if (map != null) {
  .. use the map
} else {
  .. some default behavior
}
```

This is **not safe** even though it probably appears as though it is. The problem is that there is no [*happens-before*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) relationship between the set of `SomeObject.MAP` and the subsequent read on another thread, so the reading thread is free to see a partially constructed map. This can pretty much do *anything* and even in practice it does things like [put the reading thread into an infinite loop](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html).

To safely publish the map, you need to establish a *happens-before* relationship between the *writing of the reference* to the `HashMap` (i.e., the *publication*) and the subsequent readers of that reference (i.e., the consumption). Conveniently, there are only a few easy-to-remember ways to [accomplish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5458848/149138) that<sup>[1]</sup>:

1. Exchange the reference through a properly locked field ([JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5))
2. Use static initializer to do the initializing stores ([JLS 12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4))
3. Exchange the reference via a volatile field ([JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)), or as the consequence of this rule, via the AtomicX classes
4. Initialize the value into a final field ([JLS 17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)).

The ones most interesting for your scenario are (2), (3) and (4). In particular, (3) applies directly to the code I have above: if you transform the declaration of `MAP` to:

```
public static volatile HashMap<Object, Object> MAP;
```

then everything is kosher: readers who see a *non-null* value necessarily have a *happens-before* relationship with the store to `MAP` and hence see all the stores associated with the map initialization.

The other methods change the semantics of your method, since both (2) (using the static initalizer) and (4) (using *final*) imply that you cannot set `MAP` dynamically at runtime. If you don't *need* to do that, then just declare `MAP` as a `static final HashMap<>` and you are guaranteed safe publication.

In practice, the rules are simple for safe access to "never-modified objects":

If you are publishing an object which is not *inherently immutable* (as in all fields declared `final`) and:

- You already can create the object that will be assigned at the moment of declaration<sup>a</sup>: just use a `final` field (including `static final` for static members).
- You want to assign the object later, after the reference is already visible: use a volatile field<sup>b</sup>.

That's it!

In practice, it is very efficient. The use of a `static final` field, for example, allows the JVM to assume the value is unchanged for the life of the program and optimize it heavily. The use of a `final` member field allows *most* architectures to read the field in a way equivalent to a normal field read and doesn't inhibit further optimizations<sup>c</sup>.

Finally, the use of `volatile` does have some impact: no hardware barrier is needed on many architectures (such as x86, specifically those that don't allow reads to pass reads), but some optimization and reordering may not occur at compile time - but this effect is generally small. In exchange, you actually get more than what you asked for - not only can you safely publish one `HashMap`, you can store as many more not-modified `HashMap`s as you want to the same reference and be assured that all readers will see a safely published map.

For more gory details, refer to [Shipilev](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/) or [this FAQ by Manson and Goetz](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalRight).

---

[1] Directly quoting from [shipilev](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/).

---

<sup>a</sup> That sounds complicated, but what I mean is that you can assign the reference at construction time - either at the declaration point or in the constructor (member fields) or static initializer (static fields).

<sup>b</sup> Optionally, you can use a `synchronized` method to get/set, or an `AtomicReference` or something, but we're talking about the minimum work you can do.

c Some architectures with very weak memory models (I'm looking at *you*, Alpha) may require some type of read barrier before a `final` read - but these are very rare today.

Comment: `never modify` `HashMap` not mean the `state of the map object` is thread safe I think. God knows the library implementation, if the official document not said it is thread safe.

Comment: @JiangYD - you are right there is a grey area there in some cases: when we say "modify" what we really mean is any action that internally performs some _writes_ that might race with reads or writes on other threads. These writes might be internal implementation details, so even an operation that seems "read only" like `get()` might in fact perform some writes, say updating some statistics (or in the case of access-ordered `LinkedHashMap` updating the access order). So a well written class should provide some documentation which makes it clear if ...

Comment: ... apparently "read only" operations are really internally read-only in the thread-safety sense. In C++ standard library for example, there is a blanket rule that member function marked `const` are truly read-only in such a sense (internally, they may still perform writes, but these will have to be made thread-safe). There is no `const` keyword in Java and I'm not aware of any documented blanket guarantee, but _in general_ the standard library classes behave as expected, and exceptions are documented (see the `LinkedHashMap` example where RO ops like `get` are explicitly mentioned as unsafe).

Comment: @JiangYD - finally, getting back to your original question, for `HashMap` we actually have [right in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) the thread-safety behavior for this class: _If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.)_

Comment: So for `HashMap` methods that we expect to be read-only, are read-only, as they do not structurally modify the `HashMap`. Of course, this guarantee might not hold for arbitrary other `Map` implementations, but the question is about `HashMap` specifically.

Comment: @BeeOnRope- Make scenes

Comment: @BeeOnRope Does construction of the `HashMap` before invoking `SomeClass.setMap` onto the now volatile `SomeClass.MAP` field need to be synchronized in some way to ensure there's no reordering of instructions with respect to the act of storing the newly constructed `HashMap` onto `volatile` `SomeClass.MAP`? [This article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-hashmap/index.html) suggests that the 'HashMap` 'put`'s need to be synchronized to ensure that other threads see the internals of the map in a consistent state, in addition to using volatile.

Comment: @Jose - no, because a write to a volatile field synchronizes with the subsequent read. All actions prior to the write on the same thread happen-before the write, and the read happens-before all use on the consuming thread, so all the construction actions will be ordered before consumption by the accesses to the volatile field.

Answer (score 74):

Jeremy Manson, the god when it comes to the Java Memory Model, has a three part blog on this topic - because in essence you are asking the question "Is it safe to access an immutable HashMap" - the answer to that is yes.  But you must answer the predicate to that question which is - "Is my HashMap immutable".  The answer might surprise you - Java has a relatively complicated set of rules to determine immutability.

For more info on the topic, read Jeremy's blog posts:

Part 1 on Immutability in Java:
http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/04/immutability-in-java.html

Part 2 on Immutability in Java:
http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/07/immutability-in-java-part-2.html

Part 3 on Immutability in Java:
http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/07/immutability-in-java-part-3.html

Comment: It's a good point, but I'm relying on static initialization, during which no references escape, so it should be safe.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a highly rated answer (or even an answer). It doesn't, for one, even _answer_ the question and it doesn't mention the one key principle that will decide whether it is safe or not: **safe publication**. The "answer" boils down to "it's trickly" and here are three (complex) links you can read.

Comment: He does answer the question at the very end of the first sentence. In terms of being an answer, he's raising the point that immutability (alluded to in the first paragraph of the question) is not straightforward, along with valuable resources that explain that topic further.  The points don't measure whether it's an answer, it measures whether the answer was "useful" to others.  The answer being accepted means it was the answer the OP was looking for, which your answer received.

Comment: @Jesse he is not answering the question at the end of the first sentence, he's answerig the question "is it safe to access an immutable object", which may or may not apply to the OP's question as he points out in the next sentence. Essentially this is a almost a link-only "go figure it yourself" type answer, which is not a good answer for SO. As for the upvotes, I think it's more a function of being 10.5 years old and a frequently searched topic. It has received only a very few net upvotes in the last several years so maybe people are coming around :).

Answer (score 38):

The reads are safe from a synchronization standpoint but not a memory standpoint.  This is something that is widely misunderstood among Java developers including here on Stackoverflow. (Observe the rating of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84285/calling-threadstart-within-its-own-constructor#84937) for proof.)

If you have other threads running, they may not see an updated copy of the HashMap if there is no memory write out of the current thread.  Memory writes occur through the use of the synchronized or volatile keywords, or through uses of some java concurrency constructs.

See [Brian Goetz's article on the new Java Memory Model](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03304/) for details.

Comment: Sorry for the dual submission Heath, I only noticed yours after I submitted mine. :)

Comment: I'm just glad there are other people here that actually understand the memory-effects.

Comment: Indeed, though no thread will see the object before it is initialized properly, so I don't think that is a concern in this case.

Comment: That depends entirely on how the object is initialised.

Comment: The question says that once the HashMap has been initialised, he doesn't intend to update it any further. From, then on,he just wants to use it as a read-only data structure. I think, it would be safe to do so, provided, the data stored in his Map is immutable.

Comment: What are you basing this on? Did you read the links I provided in my answer?

Comment: To be clear, there are no such terms as "memory write outs" or similar things in the standard. The JLS describes an abstract model which is mostly based on the _happens-before_ relationship, so a claim like _"The reads are safe from a synchronization standpoint but not a memory standpoint."_ can't really be validated (and it isn't clear to me what you mean by it). The key is _safe publication_, which ensures that all other threads that see the reference will see the hash map fully constructed. Without that you are unsafe from _any_ standpoint.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that you need a `happens-before` relationship via a volatile member or final member within a constructor.

Answer (score 12):

After a bit more looking, I found this in the [java doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (emphasis mine):

> Note that this implementation is not
>   synchronized.  **If multiple threads
>   access a hash map concurrently, and at
>   least one of the threads modifies the
>   map structurally, it must be
>   synchronized externally.** (A structural
>   modification is any operation that
>   adds or deletes one or more mappings;
>   merely changing the value associated
>   with a key that an instance already
>   contains is not a structural
>   modification.)

This seems to imply that it will be safe, assuming the converse of the statement there is true.

Comment: While this is excellent advice, as other answers state, there is a more nuanced answer in the case of an immutable, safely published map instance.  But you should do that only if You Know What You're Doing.

Comment: Hopefully with questions like these more of us can Know What We're Doing.

Comment: This isn't really correct.  As the other answers state, there must be a *happens-before* between the last modification and all subsequent "thread safe" reads.  Normally this means you must safely publish the object *after* it has been created and its modifications are made.  See the first, marked correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

One note is that under some circumstances, a get() from an unsynchronized HashMap can cause an infinite loop.  This can occur if a concurrent put() causes a rehash of the Map.

http://lightbody.net/blog/2005/07/hashmapget_can_cause_an_infini.html

Comment: Actually I have seen this hang the JVM without consuming CPU (which is perhaps worse)

Comment: I *think* this code has been rewritten such that it's no longer possible to get the infinite loop.  But you still shouldn't be hitting getting and putting from an unsynchronized HashMap for other reasons.

Comment: @AlexMiller even aside from the other reasons (I assume you're referring to safe publishing), I don't think an implementation change should be a reason to loosen access restrictions, unless it's explicitly allowed for by the documentation. As it happens, the [HashMap Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for Java 8 still contains this warning: `Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.`

Answer (score 7):

There is an important twist though. It's safe to access the map, but in general it's not guaranteed that all threads will see exactly the same state (and thus values) of the HashMap. This might happen on multiprocessor systems where the modifications to the HashMap done by one thread (e.g., the one that populated it) can sit in that CPU's cache and won't be seen by threads running on other CPUs, until a memory fence operation is performed ensuring cache coherence. The Java Language Specification is explicit on this one: the solution is to acquire a lock (synchronized (...)) which emits a memory fence operation. So, if you are sure that after populating the HashMap each of the threads acquires ANY lock, then it's OK from that point on to access the HashMap from any thread until the HashMap is modified again.

Comment: I'm not sure that thread accessing it will acquire any lock, but I am sure they won't get a reference to the object until after it has been initialized, so I don't think they can have a stale copy.

Comment: @Alex: The reference to the HashMap can be volatile to create the same memory visibility guarantees. @Dave: It *is* possible to see references to new objs before the work of its ctor becomes visible to your thread.

Comment: @Christian In the general case, certainly.  I was saying that in this code, it isn't.

Comment: Acquiring a RANDOM lock doesn't garantee the whole thread cpu cache to be cleared. It depends on the JVM implementation, and it's very likely not done this way.

Comment: I agree with Pierre, I don't think that acquiring any lock will be enough. You have to synchronize on the same lock for the changes to become visible.

Answer (score 5):

According to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03304/ # Initialization safety you can make your HashMap a final field and after the constructor finishes it would be safely published.

...
Under the new memory model, there is something similar to a happens-before relationship between the write of a final field in a constructor and the initial load of a shared reference to that object in another thread.
...

Comment: This answer is low quality, it is the same as the answer from @taylor gauthier but with less details.

Comment: Ummmm... not to be an ass, but you have it backwards.  Taylor said "no, go look at this blog post, the answer might surprise you", whereas this answer actually adds something new that I didn't know...  About a happens-before relationship of the write of a final field in a constructor.

This answer is excellent, and I'm glad I read it.

Comment: Huh? This is the _only_ correct answer I found after scrolling through the higher rated answers. The key is _safely published_ and this is the only answer that even mentions it.

Answer (score 5):

This question is addressed in Brian Goetz's "Java Concurrency in Practice" book (Listing 16.8, page 350):

```java
@ThreadSafe
public class SafeStates {
    private final Map<String, String> states;

    public SafeStates() {
        states = new HashMap<String, String>();
        states.put("alaska", "AK");
        states.put("alabama", "AL");
        ...
        states.put("wyoming", "WY");
    }

    public String getAbbreviation(String s) {
        return states.get(s);
    }
}
```

Since `states` is declared as `final` and its initialization is accomplished within the owner's class constructor, any thread who later reads this map is guaranteed to see it as of the time the constructor finishes, provided no other thread will try to modify the contents of the map.

Answer (score 2):

So the scenario you described is that you need to put a bunch of data into a Map, then when you're done populating it you treat it as immutable. One approach that is "safe" (meaning you're enforcing that it really is treated as immutable) is to replace the reference with `Collections.unmodifiableMap(originalMap)` when you're ready to make it immutable.

For an example of how badly maps can fail if used concurrently, and the suggested workaround I mentioned, check out this bug parade entry: [bug_id=6423457](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6423457)

Comment: This is "safe" in that it enforces the immutability, but it doesn't address the thread safety issue.  If the map is safe to access with the UnmodifiableMap wrapper then it is safe without it, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Be warned that even in single-threaded code, replacing a ConcurrentHashMap with a HashMap may not be safe. ConcurrentHashMap forbids null as a key or value. HashMap does not forbid them (don't ask).

So in the unlikely situation that your existing code might add a null to the collection during setup (presumably in a failure case of some kind), replacing the collection as described will change the functional behaviour.

That said, provided you do nothing else concurrent reads from a HashMap are safe.

[Edit: by "concurrent reads", I mean that there are not also concurrent modifications.

Other answers explain how to ensure this. One way is to make the map immutable, but it's not necessary. For example, the JSR133 memory model explicitly defines starting a thread to be a synchronised action, meaning that changes made in thread A before it starts thread B are visible in thread B.

My intent is not to contradict those more detailed answers about the Java Memory Model. This answer is intended to point out that even aside from concurrency issues, there is at least one API difference between ConcurrentHashMap and HashMap, which could scupper even a single-threaded program which replaced one with the other.]

Comment: Thanks for the warning, but there's no attempts to use null keys or values.

Comment: Thought there wouldn't be. nulls in collections are a crazy corner of Java.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer.   "Concurrent reads from a HashMap are safe" by itself is incorrect.  It doesn't state whether the reads are occurring against a map that is mutable or immutable.  To be correct it should read "Concurrent reads from an immutable HashMap are safe"

Comment: Not according to the articles you yourself linked to: the requirement is that the map must not be changed (and previous changes must be visible to all the reader threads), not that it be immutable (which is a technical term in Java and is a sufficient but not necessary condition for safety).

Comment: Also a note... initializing a class implicitly synchronizes on the same lock (yes, you can deadlock in static field initializers), so if your initialization happens statically, it would be impossible for anyone else to see it before initialization is complete, as they would have to be blocked in the ClassLoader.loadClass method on the same lock acquired...  And if you are wondering about different classloaders having different copies of the same field, you would be correct... but that would be orthogonal to the notion of race conditions; static fields of a classloader share a memory fence.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html

here is the source for HashMap. As you can tell, there is absolutely no locking / mutex code there.

This means that while its okay to read from a HashMap in a multithreaded situation, I'd definitely use a ConcurrentHashMap if there were multiple writes.

Whats interesting is that both the .NET HashTable and Dictionary<K,V> have built in synchronization code.

Comment: I think there are classes where simply reading concurrently can get you into trouble, because of internal use of temporary instance variables, for example.  So one probably needs to carefully examine source, more than a quick scan for locking / mutex code.

Answer (score 0):

If the initialization and every put is synchronized you are save.

Following code is save because the classloader will take care of the synchronization:

```
public static final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
static {
  map.put("A","A");

}
```

Following code is save because the writing of volatile will take care of the synchronization.

```
class Foo {
  volatile HashMap<String, String> map;
  public void init() {
    final HashMap<String, String> tmp = new HashMap<>();
    tmp.put("A","A");
    // writing to volatile has to be after the modification of the map
    this.map = tmp;
  }
}
```

This will also work if the member variable is final because final is also volatile. And if the method is a constructor.