# Do I need a synchronized Map in implementing the EJBHomeFactory Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, ejb, jndi

When you want to call an `EJBBean` from the client, first you need to get hold of an `EJBHome` object reference through JNDI lookup. This code needs to be executed each time you need to work with the `EJBBean` so is gets redundant and expensive.

To solve this problem, you can cache the `EJBHome` object references and reuse them again and again from the cache without repeating the JNDI lookup.

This is the [`EJBHomeFactory Pattern`](http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/EJB.htm#EJB109) (or a more generic Service Locator Pattern).

The majority of implementations I have seen use a synchronized `Map` as the cache, or a `Hashtable`. If the cache is constructed when the application is deployed on the server and no modifications are made to the cache afterwards (only get() methods are performed) do I really need  a synchronized `Map` or a `HashMap` will do?

I know `HashMap` is not safe if at least one of the threads modifies the map (there is even a SO post on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104184/is-it-safe-to-get-values-from-a-java-util-hashmap-from-multiple-threads-no-modif)) but in this case threads only perform reads.

So, is a `HashMap` safe to use in the `EJBHomeFactory Pattern`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee the life-cycle is as you describe it seems clear that the unsynchronized  HashMap should be OK. However, my instinct is that this is building in a brittle dependency on your current deployment pattern.

If you use a synchronized datastructure then you **know** it's safe now and in the future. Unless you have concrete evidence that the synchronisation is truly impacting performance I would go with the "obviously correct" implementation.

In passing, several leading app servers actually cache the results of JNDI lookups so it's not clear how much saving the pattern your using actually gives - though I must admit I do tend to use it myself.

EJB references themselves can be reused, so in fact the frequency of going to the home can be kept quite low. If extreme performance is the objective this may be a further avenue to explore.