# Safe Publication without happens-before? Anyhow besides final?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, visibility

According to JCP (16.2.2. Safe Publication):

> This happens-before guarantee is actually a **stronger promise of visibility and ordering than made by safe publication**. When X is safely published from A to B, the safe publication guarantees visibility of the state of X, but not of the state of other variables A may have touched. But if A putting X on a queue happens-before B fetches X from that queue, not only does B see X in the state that A left it (assuming that X has not been subsequently modified by A or anyone else), but B sees everything A did before the handoff (again, subject to the same caveat)

I'm wondering when safe publication can be without happens-before, i.e. w/o using volatile/atomics or synchronization (or via frameworks such as AQS which use any of listed inside)?

One case is final fields in immutable object, where you can publish it as is w/o any additional steps.

Are there any other cases?

UPD: re-read 3.5.3. Safe Publication Idioms, another case - "Initializing an object reference from a static initializer". Seems now these are all options.

Comment: Do you have a link for your citation? It is not in the [current JLS (third edition)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).

Comment: it's from "Java Concurrency in Practice" book

Comment: Ah, thanks. From the acronym JCP I first thought about the [Java Community Process](http://jcp.org/), and this has no such numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything besides `final`, and a glance at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html seems to confirm this. Chapter 17.4 deals with everything except `final`, which is explained separately in 17.5.

It should be noted, though, that anything internal to the JVM must always be made visible before it can possibly contribute to a data race in the Java code. This affects mostly array lengths, virtual table pointers and String contents. These can never be seen as uninitialized or otherwise inconsistent.

Answer (score 3):

All list of cases you may find in Java In Concurrency:

> To publish an object safely, both the
>   reference to the object and the
>   object's state must be made visible to
>   other threads at the same time. A
>   properly constructed object can be
>   safely published by:
>
> Initializing an object reference from
>   a static initializer;
>
> Storing a reference to it into a
>   volatile field or AtomicReference;
>
> Storing a reference to it into a final
>   field of a properly constructed
>   object; or
>
> Storing a reference to it into a field
>   that is properly guarded by a lock.

Answer (score 1):

static initialization is done inside `synchronized(class)`, so it's very strong.

while `final` semantics is weaker, I doubt the implementation is really that weak.

Doug Lea's had a proposal for more primitive fences,  http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2009-January/005743.html