# java map concurrent update

Tags: java, concurrency, dictionary

I'm trying to create a `Map` with `int` values and increase them by multiple threads. two or more threads might increase the same key.

`ConcurrentHashMap` documentation was very unclear to me since it sais that:

`Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove)`

I wonder if the following code using `ConcurrentHashMap` will works **correctly**:

`myMap.put(X, myMap.get(X) + 1);`

if not, how can I manage such thing?

Comment: In Java 8, this can safely be done with `myMap.merge(X, 1, Integer::sum)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Concurrent map will not help thread safety of your code. You still can get race condition:

```
Thread-1: x = 1, get(x)
Thread-2: x = 1, get(x)
Thread-1: put(x + 1) => 2
Thread-2: put(x + 1) => 2
```

Two increments happened, but you still get only +1. You need a concurrent map only if you aim for modifying the map itself, not its content. Even the simplest [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is [threadsafe for concurrent reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104184/is-it-safe-to-get-values-from-a-java-util-hashmap-from-multiple-threads-no-modi), given the map is not mutated anymore.

So instead of a threadsafe map for primitive type, you need a threadsafe wrapper for the type. Either something from `java.util.concurrent.atomic` or roll your own locked container if needing an arbitrary type.

Comment: I have spent crazy time asking my self why on earth a  collection wrapped in an AtomicReference gets always unacurate when processed concurently. Then i saw your reply,  burdden unloaded !

Answer (score 4):

One idea would be combining ConcurrentMap with AtomicInteger, which has a increment method.

```
 AtomicInteger current = map.putIfAbsent(key, new AtomicInteger(1));
 int newValue = current == null ? 1 :current.incrementAndGet();
```

or (more efficiently, thanks @Keppil) with an extra code guard to avoid unnecessary object creation:

```
 AtomicInteger current = map.get(key);
 if (current == null){
     current = map.putIfAbsent(key, new AtomicInteger(1));
 }
 int newValue = current == null ? 1 : current.incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: if you use a ConcurrentMap there is no point in also using atomic integers, ConcurrentHashMap.replace(K, V, V) is made for this.

Comment: If updates a rare, a simple synchronized like @dflemstr suggests will also work. Not sure how much throughput you need to justify AtomicInteger.

Comment: @jolivier `replace` is subject to retrying, whereas `getAndIncrement` is not.

Comment: I usually check if the value exists before the `putIfAbsent()` to avoid creating a new `AtomicInteger` every time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the same retrying that is wrapped in `getAndIncrement`, I agree its easier to write with an AtomicInteger but for me its overkill.

Comment: @jolivier I'd definitely avoid implementing my own retry logic every time. For me this fully justifies the use of `AtomicInteger`. It does the retrying natively, in a way that cannot even be reproduced through Java.

Comment: @jolivier You understand a replace will effect other entries in the CHM?  Each replace will acquire a lock for that particular bucket.  If you have even a few collisions this will degrade performance for other AtomicIntegers in the CHM.  And if anything, `replace` is unbelievable overkill.  Using a thread safe incrementing integer is much less overkill then implementing your own.

Comment: @JohnVint I see, my remarks where more on an general interface level: there is no point in putting a thread safe structure in another thread safe structure in this case, only the container need to be thread safe. I was not considering implementations and in this particular case (incrementing an integer) its clear that the AtomicInteger is far easier to use than my `for(;;) {get;replace;}`. I was also assuming there were concurrent map implementation that were more efficient by CASing but I'm unsure now i'll go back to CHMV8 and see...

Comment: According to documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29 `putIfAbsent` may return `null`. Won't your code throw NPE in certain scenario?

Comment: @Tvaroh: True. It seems you need a null check here. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Best practice. You can use HashMap and AtomicInteger. 
Test code:

```
public class HashMapAtomicIntegerTest {
    public static final int KEY = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, AtomicInteger> concurrentHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, AtomicInteger>();
        concurrentHashMap.put(HashMapAtomicIntegerTest.KEY, new AtomicInteger());
        List<HashMapAtomicCountThread> threadList = new ArrayList<HashMapAtomicCountThread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            HashMapAtomicCountThread testThread = new HashMapAtomicCountThread(
                    concurrentHashMap);
            testThread.start();
            threadList.add(testThread);
        }
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            for (int i = index; i < 500; i++) {
                HashMapAtomicCountThread testThread = threadList.get(i);
                if (testThread.isAlive()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    index++;
                }
            }
            if (index == 500) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The result value should be " + 5000000
                + ",actually is"
                + concurrentHashMap.get(HashMapAtomicIntegerTest.KEY));
    }
}

class HashMapAtomicCountThread extends Thread {
    HashMap<Integer, AtomicInteger> concurrentHashMap = null;

    public HashMapAtomicCountThread(
            HashMap<Integer, AtomicInteger> concurrentHashMap) {
        this.concurrentHashMap = concurrentHashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            concurrentHashMap.get(HashMapAtomicIntegerTest.KEY)
                    .getAndIncrement();
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> The result value should be 5000000,actually is5000000

Or HashMap and synchronized, but much slower than the former

```
public class HashMapSynchronizeTest {

    public static final int KEY = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        hashMap.put(KEY, 0);
        List<HashMapSynchronizeThread> threadList = new ArrayList<HashMapSynchronizeThread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            HashMapSynchronizeThread testThread = new HashMapSynchronizeThread(
                    hashMap);
            testThread.start();
            threadList.add(testThread);
        }
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            for (int i = index; i < 500; i++) {
                HashMapSynchronizeThread testThread = threadList.get(i);
                if (testThread.isAlive()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    index++;
                }
            }
            if (index == 500) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The result value should be " + 5000000
                + ",actually is" + hashMap.get(KEY));
    }
}

class HashMapSynchronizeThread extends Thread {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = null;

    public HashMapSynchronizeThread(
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap) {
        this.hashMap = hashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            synchronized (hashMap) {
                hashMap.put(HashMapSynchronizeTest.KEY,
                        hashMap
                                .get(HashMapSynchronizeTest.KEY) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> The result value should be 5000000,actually is5000000

Use ConcurrentHashMap will get the wrong results.

```
public class ConcurrentHashMapTest {

    public static final int KEY = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        concurrentHashMap.put(KEY, 0);
        List<CountThread> threadList = new ArrayList<CountThread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            CountThread testThread = new CountThread(concurrentHashMap);
            testThread.start();
            threadList.add(testThread);
        }
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            for (int i = index; i < 500; i++) {
                CountThread testThread = threadList.get(i);
                if (testThread.isAlive()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    index++;
                }
            }
            if (index == 500) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The result value should be " + 5000000
                + ",actually is" + concurrentHashMap.get(KEY));
    }
}

class CountThread extends Thread {
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> concurrentHashMap = null;

    public CountThread(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> concurrentHashMap) {
        this.concurrentHashMap = concurrentHashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            concurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMapTest.KEY,
                    concurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMapTest.KEY) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> The result value should be 5000000,actually is11759

Answer (score 1):

You could just put the operation in a `synchronized (myMap) {...}` block.

Comment: although this answer is theoretically correct, we should not do because of performance implications.

Comment: @bestwishes what performance implications do you mean here?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code changes the values of your map concurrently so this will not work.

If multiple threads can `put` values into your map, you  have to use a concurrent map like ConcurrentHashMap with non thread safe values like `Integer`. [ConcurrentMap.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#replace%28K,%20V%29) will then do what you want (or use `AtomicInteger` to ease your code).

If your threads will only change the values (and not add/change the keys) of your map, then you can use a *standard map* storing *thread safe values* like [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). Then your thread will call:`map.get(key).incrementAndGet()` for instance.