# Shared thread access to array in servlet. Which implementation to use?

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

Lets say I have a code like this in my servlet:

```
private static final String RESOURCE_URL_PATTERN = "resourceUrlPattern";
private static final String PARAM_SEPARATOR = "|";

private List<String> resourcePatterns;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    String resourcePatterns = getInitParameter(RESOURCE_URL_PATTERN);
    this.resourcePatterns = com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(PARAM_SEPARATOR).trimResults().splitToList(resourcePatterns);
}
```

Is this thread safe to use `'resourcePatterns'` if it will never be modified?

Lets say like this:

```
private boolean isValidRequest(String servletPath) {
    for (String resourcePattern : resourcePatterns) {
        if (servletPath.matches(resourcePattern)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Should I use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `ArrayList` is OK in this case?

Comment: Will the init() method will be called and completed before any call to isValidRequest ? Also I think you may have some memory issues as your list is not at least volatile

Comment: @PNS Interesting point. init() is called before. But 'resourcePatterns' is not volatile. It makes me wonder - should I add volatile or it's an overhead?

Comment: Too long for comment, srooy, read my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, List is fine to read from multiple threads concurrently, so long as nothing's writing.

For more detailed information on this, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/104636/5856415) that explains this further. There are some important gotchas.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you provide a url to doc (or concept) that proves your point?

Answer (score 1):

From java concurrency in practice we have:

> To publish an object safely, both the reference to the object and the
>   object's state must be made visible to other threads at the same time.
>   A properly constructed object can be safely published by:
>
> Initializing an object reference from a static initializer. Storing a
>   reference to it into a volatile field. Storing a reference to it into
>   a final field. Storing a reference to it into a field that is properly
>   guarded by a (synchronized) lock.

your list is neither of these. I suggest making it final as this will make your object *effectively immutable* which in this case would be enough. If init() is called several times you should make it volatile instead. With this I of course assume that NO changes to the element of the list occur and that you don't expose any elements of the list either (as in a `getElementAtPosition(int pos)` method or the like.

Comment: since it's a servlet I can not make 'resourcePatterns' a final field. But what if I make init() method synchonized? According to doc that you provided it should work.

Comment: Well, that would work. But then you really should go for the volatile instead. This is exactly the kind of case where that is usable. You have a field that does not have any synchronization requirements other than with memory.