# Can I use the same instance in multiple threads running in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it fine/safe if I have multiple threads running in parallel and each thread uses the same `HashMap` instance? The `HashMap` object will only be used to read data. There will be no writing data to the `HashMap` in any of the threads.

To be clear, the `HashMap` instance is a member of a base class and I will be calling the background threads in its subclasses. Those threads will then refer to the `HashMap` object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104184/is-it-safe-to-get-values-from-a-java-util-hashmap-from-multiple-threads-no-modi

Comment: if you're only **reading** from the same field you can safely use it - but do notice that multiple threads may read the same value at the same time.

Comment: @mastov thank you! didn't find this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the threads are only reading from the `HashMap`, then it is no problem. You will get into trouble when at least one thread is modifying the `HashMap` while others might be reading from it concurrently.

Java does have other `Map` implementations that are safe for concurrent use, such as `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Perhaps add the "this implementation is not synchronized" quote from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html?

Comment: @AndyTurner that's not really relevant when threads are only reading and not writing to the `HashMap`.

Comment: Well, it sort of is. It says that it is necessary to synchronize when structurally modifying the map and reading it from multiple threads. Whilst this doesn't explicitly state that synchronisation is not necessary when only reading, I think this is implied by the absence.