# is there any way to confirm if the thread is killed at the end of execution?

Tags: java

is there any way to confirm if the thread is killed at the end of execution? If the garbage collector takes  long time to destroy the threads even when they are available for GC, out of memory exceptions may arise. to get rid of those kind of issues, it would be good to know if the threads have been destroyed.

As of now, my understanding is that at the end of run method , the thread gets killed and we need not do anything explicitly to kill the thread instance.

Thanks in advance!

```
class A
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new TestA());
         t.start();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new TestB());
         t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new TestC());
         t2.start();
    }
}
class TestA implements Runnable {
Thread t;

    public void run() {
           for(...){
           try{

           }catch()
           {
            ....
           }
           } 
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right that "at the end of run method, the thread gets killed and we need not do anything explicitly to kill the thread instance". Simply letting the thread leave its `run()` method normally is enough.

If you want to make sure that a particular thread has terminated, then [Thread.isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29) will check, and [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) will wait until it happens. If you have a particular set of threads that you're worried about, then keep a reference to them somewhere, and check up on them using these methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces()
```

gets you a current map of threads/stacktraces. However I would normally expect the JVM to clear up the threads upon exit from `run()`. Obviously if you're using some sort of thread pooling then that's not the case.

Comment: thank you so much for  your quick response. this is how i create the threads in my program. i have placed it as part of my question. hope i am doing the correct way. i keep reading in many articles that even expert developers find it difficult to develop bug free multithreaded programs.. thanks again!

Comment: Hi Brian, i am not using any thread pooling in my application. i am creating only 3 threads in the main method of my calling program and when the run() terminates, the 3 threads should be destroyed definitely. also, i have given my code snippet above. Please let me know if my understanding is correct. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some softwares like **visualvm** to monitor the thread states . 
These kind of softwares will give you full flexibility to profile your application in a visual way.

To check the state of a thread , you can call the getState() method on a thread object to see the state of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc of OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) says:

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because
>   it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the
>   garbage collector.

So, if a thread is not running anymore and is eligible to GC, the GC will try to collect it before throwing an OOM. Like with any other object.

Comment: thank you so much for  your quick response. this is how i create the threads in my program. i have placed it as part of my question. hope i am doing the correct way. i keep reading in many articles that even expert developers find it difficult to develop bug free multithreaded programs.. thanks again!

Comment: You should never start a thread from a constructor. That is very bad practice. Construct your object, and then start it.

Comment: Hi Nizet, thanks for letting me know. i have removed the constructor and changed the main(). I have modified the code in my question above. Please have a look at it and let me know if it is fine. Also, i am curious to know why it is a bad practice to start thread from a constructor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623285/java-why-not-to-start-a-thread-in-the-constructor-how-to-terminate

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to confirm if the thread is killed at the end of execution?

There's no sense confirming something you know to be true.  Whenever the JVM process dies, all its threads are automatically killed by the operating system.  Any other behavior is a bug in the OS.

> If the garbage collector takes long time to destroy the threads even when they are available for GC, out of memory exceptions may arise.

The garbage collector doesn't kill threads - the JVM wraps operating-system-specific thread libraries into a consistent Java-language thread abstraction, so those thread libraries determine when a thread dies.

> my understanding is that at the end of run method, the thread gets killed and we need not do anything explicitly to kill the thread instance.

That is correct.

Comment: thank you so much for  your quick response. this is how i create the threads in my program. i have placed it as part of my question. hope i am doing the correct way. i keep reading in many articles that even expert developers find it difficult to develop bug free multithreaded programs.. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you look up in the javadoc for the [Thread class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) you will see many methods that might help you check what you want, for example:

*activeCount()* : Returns the number of active threads in the current thread's thread group.

You can use this as a debug method.

*isAlive()* : Tests if this thread is alive.

To check if a specific thread is alive.

*join()* : Waits for this thread to die.

If you call this at the end of your method then it will wait for the thread to join (i.e. to end execution) before advancing. If you call for all threads, then you are sure that all have finished when the main() has finished.

*destroy()* : Destroys this thread, without any cleanup.

Does what it says, but I would never suggest this.

Hope it helps!