# What are the various ways by which the 'this' can escape in Java?

Tags: java, synchronization, this

There is a question on Stack Overflow on why [starting a thread inside the constructor is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623285/java-why-not-to-start-a-thread-in-the-constructor-how-to-terminate) . I realised that the result of such a thing will be that 'this' can escaped.I also read that [publishing a EventListener from constructor](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07265/index.html) is also a bad idea for the same reason .  What are the other patterns which I should be aware of in which 'this' can escape ?

Comment: A key distinction is that 'this' escapes in a partial state before it is allowed to be completely constructed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling any instance method of your object from the constructor leaks `this` to that mathod. This may be OK as long as that method is under your control (not publicly overridable), and you are making sure you don't leak `this` further out from it. Using `this` as an argument to any method is, of course the more explicit variant, and that happens when you say `x.addEventListener(this)`. A perhaps more insdidious, since less obvious, way to leak a `this` is to not use `this` itself as an argument, but an instance of an inner/local/anonymous class, say

```
public class Main 
{
  private class MyListener extends MouseAdapter { ...}

  public Main() {
    class Listener1 extends MouseAdapter { ... }
    someSwingComponent.addMouseListener(new MyListener()); // inner class
    someSwingComponent.addMouseListener(new Listener1()); // local class
    someSwingComponent.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() { ... }); // anonymous
  }
}
```

In all these cases `this` will be the enclosing instance of the object passed as a method argument. If, on the other hand, you declare a `static` nested class, it will **not** have an enclosing instance.

Comment: So can I assume that 'this' can leaked whenever 'this' is passed as an argument to an alien method(To a Class 'Foo' an alien methods are ones that it has no control over and it can mean methods of other classes or non private/overrideable  methods of C itself)?

Comment: I see I didn't make my point clear enough in the first sentence. I meant "any instance method of `this` object" (the one whose constructor is being executed). As far as alien methods, their access level doesn't matter. What matters is whether you are passing `this` to such a method---either explicitly or implicitly through an inner class instance.