# NullPointerException on first thread

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

EDIT:

After making all the changes you suggested, the problem remained. The debugger said the lemma variable was null, but the fixes I applied didn't make things better. So, due to deadline issues,  I decided to approach the problem from another view. Thank you all for your help. :)

I am writing a small program and a `NullPointerException` drives me crazy. I have two classes: `SystemDir` and `Search`. The first one is just an encapsulation of initial directory and a search lemma. The `Search` class is shown below. Briefly, I want one thread to search the first level directory and the other one to expand the subdirectories. That's where I get the exception. The exception string is

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Search.searchFiles(Search.java:59)
at Search.<init>(Search.java:53)
at SystemDir.<init>(SystemDir.java:61)
at Search$1.run(Search.java:45)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Where the 3 points are t.start() inside the final loop, searchFiles method call, some lines above and the new SystemDir call in the run method. Can you help me please?

```
public class Search {
   private Thread t;

   public Search(String[] subFiles, final String[] subDir, final String lemma) {
       t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               for(int i=0;i<subDir.length;i++) {
                   try {
                       System.out.println(subDir[i]);
                       new SystemDir(subDir[i], lemma);
                   }
                   catch (NoDirectoryException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   }
               }
           }
       });

       searchFiles(subFiles,lemma); 
    }

    private void searchFiles(String[] subFiles, String lemma) {
       for(int i=0;i<subFiles.length;i++) {
            t.start();
            if(subFiles[i].contains(lemma)) {
                System.out.println(subFiles[i]);                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are asking questions about an exception, always provide the actually exception, the first couple of lines, and point out _which_ line corresponds to the exception line number.  Please edit your post to provide this information.

Comment: Can you format your code properly?  It's really hard to follow when your indentation is all over the map.

Comment: Looks like problem in the SystemDir constructor

Comment: Are you really starting the thread in a loop?  You can only do that once right?  Do you mean to start a new thread on each element in the array?

Comment: Also, I'm still unsure what line is throwing the NPE.  The `t.start()` line?  That doesn't make sense tho.

Comment: What's the problem with starting a thread in a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule, [never start a thread from a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623285/java-why-not-to-start-a-thread-in-the-constructor-how-to-terminate). It can create all sorts of issues, which may be responsible for the exception you get.

Create the thread like you do in your constructor, make `searchFiles` public and call that method from the client code, not from the constructor.

Apart from that, have you checked that:

- `subFiles` is not null
- none of the `subFiles[i]` is null
- `lemma` is not null

(add println statements if necessary)

and as pointed out by @Gray, you can't start a thread more than once.

Comment: I will try to fix, and return with news :)

Answer (score 2):

You have failed to posted the source code for `SystemDir`, but the stack trace says that its constructor is trying to create a *new* `Search` object in addition to the one that created the thread in the first place.

More concretely, probably the `new Search(...)` expression somewhere in SystemDir's constructor is passing `null` for `subFiles`. Is there a call to `File.list()` somewhere that you haven't checked for a null return from, perhaps? Note that `list()` returns null if it cannot list a directory at all, due to anything from missing permissions to directory-not-found.

---

Also, It appears you're attempting to start the same thread object more than once. That will cause an `IllegalThreadStateException` if there is ever more than one element in `subFiles`.

Comment: Yes, you have a point on the "list() returns null thing". I will post the SystemDir source code, in the afternoon. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not included all the code.

With the information provided:

in `searchFiles` either `t`, `subFiles`, or `subFiles[i]` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself doesn't make much sense.

That makes it hard to spot the error.

I recommend using the Eclipse debugger, and check **WHICH** value is `null`.

As far as I can tell, your problem is *within the recursion into `SystemDir`*, where you don't provide the code of.

Answer (score 0):

In your `searchFiles` method, what is the point of starting the thread in a loop? Do you want to run the thread on each execution of the loop? I think you are missing something here.

Check if some value that you are passing to the constructor is null.