# Thread as constructor or run()

Tags: java

Is there any difference between creating a thread using the run() method as opposed to using the a constructor?
I noticed that I can start the thread and it acts the same in both ways.

```
new Thread MyThread().start
```

For example, as a constructor:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    public MyThread(){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

or as the run() method

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between constructor or run()? Thanks!

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5623327/645270)

Comment: Your question is phrased in a very imprecise way. That's not the constructor, that's the difference between `Thread#start()` and `Thread#run()`.

Comment: @MattBall - Actually, the question is "_what is the difference between placing logic in the constructor vs placing it the run method when code that looks like this is executed_: `new MyThread().start();`?  Of course his example code is full of syntax errors...

Answer (score 4):

**It does not act the same in both cases**

These cases are entirely different.

First, you probably need to learn about `Thread`s and non-blocking processes. A `Thread` is used to do something asynchronously. So if you wanted to do some background task whilst doing something else then you would use a `Thread`. A good example is a GUI; you need one `Thread` to listen for GUI events (mouse clicks, button presses) and another to do any long running processing.

Now, onto your examples.

In Java a `Thread` consists of a `run` method that executes asynchronously when the `start` method is called. So when overriding `Thread` you change the `run` method. In reality you should **never** override `Thread`, you should use the constructor that takes a `Runnable`. There are many reasons for this, you should read up on concurrency.

Any code you place in your `Thread` constructor will be executed in the `Thread` that calls your constructor so this is **not** called asynchronously.

Comment: Reasons why `implements Runnable` is better than extending `Thread` are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread - basically cleaner OO design

Comment: @zapl there are other, more subtle reasons. For example a `Thread` calls `notifyAll` on itself when it dies - this is how `join` works; if you extend `Thread` and synchronise on `this` you can end up with _really_ weird outcomes...

Answer (score 3):

If you put the code in the `run` method, a new thread will be started upon invocation of `start`, which uses the `run` method as its starting point. If you put the code in the constructor, however, it will be run in the same thread as that which invoked the constructor, because a constructor is a special case of a method. Thus, if you want to start something in a new thread, put it in `run`, otherwise, put it in the constructor. Also, if you want to start a thread, never call `Thread.run`, because of the same reason not to put code in the constructor. Always call `Thread.start()`.

Comment: If you want to start something in a new thread, put your code in `Thread.run()` **AND** start the thread by using `Thread.start()`.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is this:

The code in your constructor is executed **immediately** and **synchronously** when the constructor is invoked.

The program will stop and wait for that code to complete before moving on to the next line of code.

If you put the code inside `run()` method **AND** use `Thread.start()`, the code will be executed in a separate thread (i.e. it will run asynchronously).

Your program will continue to execute (moving to the next line of code immediately) while the code in your `run()` method runs in parallel.

This is helpful if the code in `run()` takes a very long time to execute.

That's because your program can continue to do other things while it waits for the thread to finish its work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference. The constructor that creates the `Runnable` or subclass thereof runs in the main thread.

When starting a thread using:

```
new Thread(myRunnable).start();
```

you'll actually have `run(` of `myRunnable` run in the new thread.

<sub>NB You'll want to have a reference to the thread object in many cases. This code example is merely illustrative</sub>

On another note, never, ever, ever, give a thread `this` if starting within a constructor. Your computer could explode, or asphyxiation, drowning, or poisoning may occur.