# Program hanging after thread ending

Tags: java, multithreading

Basically I have a ServerSocket listener , on new incoming connection the program executes a thread to serve it , after the thread finishes , the program doesn't continue 
this is the listener

```
client = listenSocket.accept();
        new HandleConnection(client);//HandleConnections extends thread and start 
                                         //method is called in the constructor                    
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Number of clients served : " + counter);
```

this is the thread

```
public HandleConnection(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
        this.start();
}
public void run() {

        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    client.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            handler();
            System.out.println("Ending Thread !");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //System.out.println("socket closed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

the message "Ending Thread !" is executed normally , but the counter++ and the following println statement are never executed

Comment: where do you execute start method of thread?

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to answer, but I can tell you something else: your `run` method is one big resource leak.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I assume you are talking about missing `finally`  clause to close the streams?

Comment: @gray Yes. There are altogether three resources he needs to close.

Comment: OP, I wonder if you have checked for the `"Number of clients served"` message *before* the `"Ending Thread !"` message---because that is where it is most likely to occur in the console output.

Comment: As I mentioned above  System.out.println("Ending Thread !"); is executed , doesn't this mean the thread should finish by now ? 
also , I do close streams and socket in the handler function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the message "Ending Thread !" is executed normally , but the counter++ and the following println statement are never executed

So if `new HandleConnection(client);` actually starts a new thread (which you should not do in a constructor, see below), then the `counter++` should immediately be executed and the `"Number of clients...` message printed.  Any chance the message is appearing *above* the `"Ending Thread!"` message in your logs?  Typically it takes some time to start the actual thread so the caller will continue to execute before the `run()` method is entered.

Other comments about your code:

- As @MarkoTopolnik mentions, you need to close the input and output streams in your `run()` method.  `finally` clauses are a required pattern there.
- You should never call `Thread.start()` in an object constructor because of `Thread` race condition issues around object construction.  See: [Why not to start a thread in the constructor? How to terminate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623285/java-why-not-to-start-a-thread-in-the-constructor-how-to-terminate)
- Instead of extending `Thread` you should consider implementing `Runnable` and doing something like:

  ```
  new Thread(new HandleConnection(client)).start();
  ```
- Event better than managing the threads yourself would be to use an `ExecutorService` thread-pool for your client handlers.  See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Comment: I upped this because it does a good job explaining why we do something like the code I posted below.

Comment: true , I missed it , it's shown far up in the log , in middle of a handshake protocl log , that's why I missed it

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to perform something like this:

```
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(3030); //Create a new socket to listen on

    try
    {
        //While we are running, if a client connects
        //accept the connect and increment the client ID
        while (true)
        {
            new udSocketServer(listener.accept()).start();
        }
    }
    finally //Gracefully close
    {
        listener.close(); //Close socket object
    }
```

You could then call the shared variable 'counter' in the thread constructor. If you need more than this, let me know and I will edit.
But in reality you need a little more code for us to answer.