# Java Multiple Threads Demo not Working

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a small program to see how multiple threads can be run in Java. Not sure why I'm not getting any output:

```
class NuThread implements Runnable {
    NuThread() {
        Thread t = new Thread(this, "NuThread");
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
                System.out.println(th.getName() + ": " + i);
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
            System.out.println(th.getName() + " interrupted.");
        }
    }
}

public class MultiThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NuThread t1, t2, t3;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main interrupted.");
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not *creating* any instances of `NuThread`. This line:

```
NuThread t1, t2, t3;
```

... just declares three variables. It doesn't create any instances. You'd need something like:

```
NuThread t1 = new NuThread();
NuThread t2 = new NuThread();
NuThread t3 = new NuThread();
```

Having said that, making a constructor start a new thread is a little odd in itself... it might be better to remove that and just have:

```
// TODO: Rename NuThread to something more suitable :)
NuThread runnable = new NuThread();
Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);
Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable);
Thread t3 = new Thread(runnable);
t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.start();
```

Note that it's okay to use the same `Runnable` for all three threads, as they don't actually use any state.

Comment: Thanks! This is how threads are created in Herbert Schildt's book, although I do feel that you have a point. Something else (main?) should be creating and running threads.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating object of **NuThread**. That's why thread is not starting.

And it's not the best idea to start thread in the constructor, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623285/why-not-to-start-a-thread-in-the-constructor-how-to-terminate).