# run() is never called by Thread.start() method

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

I have written a small multithreading program.

```java
public class NewThread implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

    public NewThread() {
        t = new Thread(this, "Thread created by Thread Class.");
        System.out.println("Created by constuctor:"+ t);
        t.start(); // This will call run, because t has context as this
    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        System.out.println("run() method called.");     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewThread();
    }
}
```

This is how the book says to write it. However, I never get the `run() method called` statement in the console. Thus, it seems `run()` is never called. How can this be true?

Edit: Yes, it is bad practice to start a Thread from constructor, but that is not affecting the question. (I am getting so many down votes for that)

Comment: I would strongly recommend not starting threads in constructors. Other than that you don't wait for your new thread to start and it doesn't get the opportunity to print anything - you need to `join()` it.

Comment: what is your problem exactly, your code return this result **Created by constuctor:Thread[Thread created by Thread Class.,5,main]
run() method called.**

Comment: @YoucefLaidani no. It won't. The result is a race hazard, the outcome is unknown.

Comment: ahh ok, your question was not clear

Comment: It does not return `run() method called`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> run() is never called by Thread.start() method

You code actually works on my system but that it doesn't work on your's, demonstrates that you have a classic race condition.

Inside of `main()`, the `NewThread` is constructed but the Java language says that it can reorder operations so that the operations in a constructor can happen *after* the constructor finishes.  So it is possible that `main()` might finish *before* the `NewThread` has actually been started which can result in the JVM shutting down without running the thread.

Because of instruction reordering, you should never have a thread auto-start itself inside of the constructor.  See: [Why not to start a thread in the constructor? How to terminate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623285/why-not-to-start-a-thread-in-the-constructor-how-to-terminate/5623327#5623327)

You should instead do:

```
public NewThread() {
    t = new Thread(this, "Thread created by Thread Class.");
    System.out.println("Created by constuctor:" + t);
    // don't start here
}
public void start() {
    // start in another method
    t.start();
}
public void run() {     
    System.out.println("run() method called.");     
}
...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewThread nt = new NewThread();
    nt.start();
}
```

Since the `NewThread` has the same daemon status as your main thread (which is non-daemon) the JVM will not shutdown until `nt.run()` completes.

Comment: Useful link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0618/ (Putting it here for later ref, as you removed it from answer.)

Comment: Thanks @AnilBhaskar.  I'm still looking for a better page on the topic.