# Why Main thread is not getting preempted here?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, singleton

```
public class SingletonClass {
private static SingletonClass singletonClass;
public void executeMethod(String string) {
    System.out.print("["+string);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
private SingletonClass() {

}
public static SingletonClass getInstance() {
    if(singletonClass==null)
        singletonClass=new SingletonClass();
    return singletonClass;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SingletonClass.getInstance().executeMethod("MainThread");
    new SingleTonThread(SingletonClass.getInstance());
}
```

}

```
class SingleTonThread implements Runnable{
private SingletonClass sc;
SingleTonThread(SingletonClass singleton){
    this.sc=singleton;
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    sc.executeMethod("SingleTonThread");
}
```

}

I expected following output (as main thread should be preempted by SingleTonThread) : 
expected Output: [MainThread[SingleTonThread]
]
 Actual output :
 [MainThread]
 [SingleTonThread]

Comment: You finish executing `executeMethod("Main Thread")` - sleep and all - before you even start the other thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling:

```
SingletonClass.getInstance().executeMethod("MainThread");
```

you have blocked the main thread by calling

```
sleep(1000)
```

The following line that initiate the thread class will not be executed until

```
executeMethod("MainThread")
```

Will finish to execute

By the way it is a very bad practice to start a thread in a constructor [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623285/why-not-to-start-a-thread-in-the-constructor-how-to-terminate)